# ng-repeat add two row per repeat

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat to form the rows in a table. For each row I need to display some data that needs to span across all the cells of that row.

```
  <tr ng-repeat="cr in results.crs">
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
```

I want something like this-

```
  <tr ng-repeat="cr in results.crs">
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    </tr >
      <td colspan=2>The Special Cell</td>
    <tr>
  </tr>
```

However ,ng-repeat doesn't allow two rows per repeat.I tried doing the following but doesn't work.

```
  <tr ng-repeat="cr in results.crs">
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    </tr >
      <td>The Special Cell</td>
    <tr>
  </tr>
```

Is there a way to add two rows per repeat?

Also,can anyone suggest any alternative way to do it? I am using table structure since its easier to design and I have basic knowledge of HTML+CSS.

Comment: you should try with `<div ng-repeat=" "> <tr> <td> cell 1</td></tr> </div>` may be this will work

Answer (score 37, accepted):

use

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="cr in results.crs">
  <td>cell 1</td>
  <td>cell 2</td>
</tr >
<tr ng-repeat-end>    
  <td>The Special Cell</td>
</tr>
```

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks @Dave Bush. Appreciate your quick response and help !